# Change the JVM in an Eclipse Product

Tags: java, eclipse

Where can I add a configuration to have the Eclipse Product point to the JDK 1.5 instance on my computer instead of the default JDK 1.8 instance?

I didn't see anything at:

- */.eclipseproduct* or */configuration/config.ini*
- */plugins/orgs.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.86_1.0.200.v20090519/launcher.win32.win32.x86.properties*
- */workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.[url].[packagename].configurator.prefs* has "path.to.jdk" but it doesn't affect what the Eclipse Product uses

NOTE: I want to act as the *user* of this application and *not the developer*.

Comment: What do you mean by "act as the user"?  Eclipse can't control which Java version the user attempts to run the application with; the best you can do is document which version is needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can put an `eclipse.ini` file next to the `eclipse.exe` file. This works for Eclipse itself but also for an RCP application.

In it, you can specify `-vm <vm-path>` (search with Google for `eclipse.ini` and vm and you'll find plenty of information)

Comment: Didn't appear to work for the Eclipse Product. However, I added the same thing to the command line and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs, and you will be able to add or remove any JREs that you wish.

Comment: Clarification: I want to act as the *user* of this application and *not the developer*.

Comment: In Eclipse, you still need to have that runtime declared in order to reference it.  You don't need to use that runtime as the Eclipse compiler, but in order to set the targeted runtime of your application, Eclipse still needs some notion of what that runtime is.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a xxx.product file for the RCP you could put

```
-vm
<vm-path>
```

in the 'Program Arguments' section of 'Launching Arguments' on the 'Launching' tab in the .product file editor.

Make sure the -vm and the path are on separate lines.